# Routerlink works without anchor tag

Tags: angular, anchor, routerlink

I just noticed that **routerLink** works on any element e.g on divs, mat-card, mat-title, etc, without needing to wrap an **anchor tag** around.

Is that okay / safe to do so or you need to use it with the anchor ? Maybe it can have some bad **consequences** later if doing so ?

Answer (score 5):

I think [routerLink.navigate is a direcitve](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) which listens on an [onclick](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L18-L157) event.

So as long as using onClick is safe, you are safe to use routerLink too.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I haven't been explicit enough but I meant without using onClick. An example :  `<img mat-card-image class="example-image" src="/assets/images/baby.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu" routerLink="/family-detail/{{baby.firstname}}"
        routerLinkActive="active">`it just works without using onClick or an  anchor tag.

Comment: Look at the source code: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.9/packages/router/src/directives/router_link.ts#L18-L157

The `137: @HostListener('click') ` line means that if you use that directive, you always listen to a click event to navigate